# Getting anchor text from a webpage using xpath within YQL

Tags: yql

```
SELECT content FROM html WHERE url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_National_Parks_by_state" AND xpath="//a/text()"
```

does not work, whereas

```
SELECT * FROM html WHERE url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_National_Parks_by_state" AND xpath="//a/text()"
```

does.

```
SELECT content FROM html WHERE url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_National_Parks_by_state" AND xpath="//a"
```

also works, it seems YQL has a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: how can I get the seperated anchor links without getting an error? SELECT * works (2nd query), but combines all anchors into one result.

Comment: what is wrong with the queries provided that "work"? are you looking for just the text inside the links, for the URLs, both, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT content FROM html WHERE url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_National_Parks_by_state" AND xpath="//a"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT href
FROM html
WHERE url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_National_Parks_by_state"
      AND xpath="//a"
```

Try it on the YQL [console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20href%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url=%22http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_National_Parks_by_state%22%20AND%20xpath=%22//a%22%0A).